# How to revoke the RefreshToken and invalidate the AccessToken at the same time in Oauth2

Tags: c#, asp.net, oauth-2.0, token, owin

I'm developing the authentication flow of a single page application (AngularJS + .Net MVC Json Rest API) using Owin Oauth2 (Authorization and Resource servers are the same).

I've chosen the Bearer Token route over the traditional cookie+session because I would like to stay stateless and also because the same Api will be used by a mobile app where token has less problem than the cookie.

This is the simplified flow:

- User submits Username/Password to the server (POST over HTTPS to the
  TokenProvider route)
- Owin creates an `AccessToken` with a claim containing
  a generated GUID (that will represent something like a Session Id) and some other claims.
- Owin creates a `RefreshToken`.
- Server creates an entry in the `RefreshToken` table with the following fields:

> GUID(PK)|RefreshToken|Ticket|DateIssued|DateExpire|DateEnd

- Server gives both the `AccessToken` and the
  `RefreshToken` to the client.
- Client stores both the `AccessToken` and `RefreshToken` into the SessionStorage.
- The client accesses the API with the `AccessToken`.

When AngularJS detects that the AccessToken is near to expire, it buffers all the requests and issues a `grant_type refresh_token request`;
the server uses the `RefreshToken` provided by the client and:

- Checks if the Refresh Token is still valid from Db (`DateExpire > GetTime() And DateEnd is Null`)
- Takes the Ticket from Db
- Creates an AccessToken from the Ticket
- Updates the DB entry with the fresh Dates, the new `RefreshToken` and the new Ticket (Note: the GUID remains the same)

When the client hits the logout server-side, the GUID read from the identity claim of the logged user is used to invalidate the entry on the table (`DateEnd = GetTime()`).
Client-side both tokens are removed from the `SessionStorage`.

In this way, I can revoke the `RefreshToken` denying any other requests to get a fresh `AccessToken`.

The problem with this approach is that there is a window of time when the authorization is revoked (ie: `RefreshToken` invalidated on DB) but the `AccessToken` is still valid (although for a limited frame of time).

What I'm thinking to do is to check the validity of the `AccessToken` on each request, taking the GUID from the user identity claims and hitting the db to check if the Refresh Token of that specific GUID is still valid.

Although it's quite trivial to make queries performing O(1), the single point of failure itself can have negative impact on the scalability and performance of the system.

Do you know another method to mitigate this problem and do you see any flaws in my approach?

Comment: Just for interest I've hit this issue with Office 365 Exchange when blocking email access to a mobile device. The user's email account is not locked until the access token expires, which was one hour exactly in this case.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your approach and it is very identical to the approach I've [blogged](http://bitoftech.net/2014/07/16/enable-oauth-refresh-tokens-angularjs-app-using-asp-net-web-api-2-owin/) about earlier, but my recommendation is not to do any DB checks when you send the access token.

Why you do not issue short-lived access tokens i.e (30 mins) and you wait until the access token lifetime is expired after revoking the refresh token. And on the client, you can clear the refresh token and access token from your client's local storage.

Comment: I do not like very much the idea that when somebody does a logout, some credential is still good to access the resource server. With your fantastic stuff on your blog about Owin and Oauth 2,  you are helping a lot of people out there. I have read that blog post hundreds of time :).

Comment: Glad it was helpful :) I agree with you it is better to revoke it completely but this how bearer tokens works :(

Comment: @TaiseerJoudeh : For bank use My Requirement:1) there is one instance for one user.2) Logout should be happen immediately and once logout successfully , token should invalidate. Is Identity is good for Bank Projects ? If not then what is the other solutions for this problem ?Because banking project should be most secure than other application!!!

Comment: [RFC 7009](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7009) proposes a way to clear access_tokens: _This document proposes an additional endpoint for OAuth authorization
   servers, which allows clients to notify the authorization server that
   a previously obtained refresh or access token is no longer needed._

Comment: above link doesn't work anymore, do we have any similar post somewhere else? if yes, please add the link

Comment: Link works for me: https://bitoftech.net/2014/07/16/enable-oauth-refresh-tokens-angularjs-app-using-asp-net-web-api-2-owin/