# Revoke access token of OAuthBearerAuthentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, oauth

I've set up the authentication for Web API which is almost identical to this blog here [oauth-refresh-tokens](http://bitoftech.net/2014/07/16/enable-oauth-refresh-tokens-angularjs-app-using-asp-net-web-api-2-owin/) from Taiseer Joudeh.

It worked perfectly until I met an issue:

- We have User A and User B are currently logged in to the system.
- User A as administrator, removes user B from the system.
- User B still has permission to access the web **until** the **token** is **expired**.

I've done some research and they all said that revoking an access token is quite difficult (or not possible in OAuth). The only thing I could do is to set the timeout shorter. It's still glitching in my mind and I do not like the idea that access token is still valid to (although a limited) frame of time after.

So, is there any better approach or any advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `refresh_token` and `access_token` as they were designed and shorten the lifetime of the access token to a duration that is acceptable for you and go as low as you need to go. Since you're both the Resource Server and Authorization Server, the asymptote means that you'll end up checking the user on every call anyhow, as suggested in the other answers, but:

using a DB to store access tokens will most probably lead to caching tokens to optimize performance, in which case you end up in the same situation as with refresh token where the cache staleness timeout is equivalent of the access token lifetime.

In the end you can't have your cake and eat it too, so I would recommend to do it as OAuth was designed to do.

Comment: Caching gives me little more control. I can decide when to delete the cache (basically the same with revoking access token). But anyway, it's still not a good approach

Comment: Consider if i am using refresh token and if i have set accesstoken expiry time to 30 minutes but in 10 minutes only
if admin changes role of that user/or delete that user from system then in this case i can delete entry from refresh token
table so that user wont be able to request access token further but still 20 minutes are left and user can access protected 
resource right.Now in case of cache and database i can simplye remove that accesstoken from cache immediately in case of
user revoke access.What do you think about this?

Comment: @HungLe Why do you think caching access token is not a good approach.Can you please tell me something about this as because i am thinking to implement caching mechanism for accesstoken

Comment: @Learning-Overthinker-Confused what kind of cache you are planning to use? In-memory cache is properly not reliable. If you are thinking of a persisted storage, you will end up with performance issues. And event with cached + db storage, it also could hurt the performance at first run since access tokens have not loaded to cache yet. Hard part is how you gonna sync cache and your db it could be little bit complicated. So as Hans said, I would recommend to do it as OAuth was designed to do.

Comment: @HungLe:How about disributed cache shared between AS and RS server so when access token is generated i will put that accesstoken in cache and when user request comes for accessing protected resource then i can validate accesstoken from cache.How about this?

Comment: A distributed cache likes Redis could also be a trade of. In one hand, it could help since it's much much faster than rdbms. That's also the same purpose of access token to avoid round trips to the db. In other hand, remember that whole dataset always resides in RAM. It can cost you. So, I guess it's up to you, but last to say, it's over complex for both coding and deployment.

Comment: @HungLe Thank you so much for the insight.Can you please provide any answers or the way you have approach this problem and what solution you use.It would be very very helpfull to me and may be to the others as well.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47412971/why-caching-access-token-is-consider-bad-in-oauth2

Answer (score 0):

Thank for referring and using my blog post, check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26071758/how-to-revoke-the-refreshtoken-and-invalidate-the-accesstoken-at-the-same-time-i/26076022#26076022) as you need to store access token identifier in DB if you want to revoke them.

Comment: Sorry but I cannot find any info of what you mentioned in that thread. Did you mean revoke "Refresh token" ?

Answer (score 0):

This is possible if you check the user against a database table every request. Something along the lines of the following in the global.asax would work.

```
    protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if ( /*check table to see if user is allowed in*/)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.User = null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I was thinking about this. It would probably hurt the performance badly if I have to query to database on every comming request. Also, it will defeat the purpose of bearer authentication.